# when submiting a form in the callback function of angularjs $http service, the data in form are lost

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, python-2.7

I want to upload a file to server, and I write my form properly:

```
<form id="imageForm" name="imageForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
```

It works well at first, but now I want to create a record in server before transmitting the file (expect to avoid waiting for uploading). So I write an asynchronous request and submit this form in its callback function, but it turns out there is no data in this second request made by the form submitting.

```
image = {};
CommonHttpService.post(url, image).then(function(data){
if(data.success){
    ToastrService.success(data.MSG, $i18next("success"));
    image_table.reload();
    image_id = data.data.image_id;
    upload_file(image_id);  //upload file by submitting form which works fine outside this callback function
} else {
    $scope.is_submitting = false;
    ToastrService.error(data.MSG, $i18next("op_failed"));
}
});
```

The CommonHttpService is an encapsulation for $http service in AngularJS. When submitting the form, I can see the data using something like `$('#form')[0]`, but they are lost in the request. It's pretty confusing. The back end I use is Django.

The CommonHttpService is implemented as:

```
.factory("CommonHttpService", function($http, $q){
  return {
    'post': function(api_url, post_data){
         var defer = $q.defer();
         $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: api_url,
             data: $.param(post_data)
         }).success(function(data, status, headers,config){
             defer.resolve(data);
         }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
             defer.reject(data);
         });
         return defer.promise;
       }
   };
})
```

Comment: Don't see how you pass the data to `CommonHttpService.post`. Show that service method

Comment: Sorry, that's an error during tests. The image I added corresponding to angular models for html elements in the form and it acts the same way when image is empty @charlietfl

Comment: Are you doing upload? `$http` is all wrong for upload and if you are trying to send form encoded data need to set proper header or if seending default json don't use `$.param`

Comment: I am using $http to create a record in database on server, and in its callback function I want to upload a file by submitting a form(in the upload_file function). But the submitting request doesnt have any data, I wonder why is that happening.@charlietfl